# Creating a new column to a data frame using a formula from another variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column to a data frame using a formula from another variable.
 
Example:
 
I have a data set "aa" is;

```
x    y 
2    3 
4    5 
6    7
```

My R code is;

```
>bb <- "x+y-2" 
>attach(aa) 
>aa$z<- bb 
>detach(aa)
```

the result is;

```
x  y  z 
2  3  x+y-2 
4  5  x+y-2 
6  7  x+y-2
```

but I want like this;

```
x  y  z 
2  3  3 
4  5  7 
6  7  11
```

Could you please help me..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want to evaluate an expression in the context, of a data frame, you can use `with` and `within`.

```
aa$z <- with(aa, x + y - 2)
```

or

```
aa <- within(aa, z <- x + y - 2)
```

Or, if your expression is in the form of a text string (you should see if there are other ways to write your code; evaluating arbitrary text strings can lead to lots of problems):

```
aa$z <- eval(parse(text="x + y - 2"), aa)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. aa$z <- eval(parse(text="x + y - 2"), aa) this code worked properly. Here we can give the variable name which containing formula.

Answer (score 12):

you can use `mutate` from the package **dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
aa <- aa %>% mutate(z = x+y-2)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

You should probably read some basic tutorials on R *other* than [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) as despite what is written there the `$` notation is more sensible and easier to understand than `attach/detach`. Try this in the meantime.

```
aa <- data.frame(x = c(2, 4, 6), y = c(3, 5, 7))
```

Which gives:

```
> aa
  x y
1 2 3
2 4 5
3 6 7
```

Then enter:

```
aa$z <- (aa$x + aa$y) - 2
```

Which gives:

```
> aa
  x y  z
1 2 3  3
2 4 5  7
3 6 7 11
```

Comment: Yes sir, this I know. But It will not take the formula from another variable.

Comment: Ah, apologies, a misunderstanding on my part - then `eval` as per the other answer is indeed what you want.