# R - subtracting different columns if condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge data frame that is like:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(1,54,23,2), B=c(1,2,4,65), C=c("+","-","-","+"))

> df
   A  B C
1  1  1 +
2 54  2 -
3 23  4 -
4  2 65 +
```

I need to subtract the rows based on different conditions, and add these results in a new column:

```
 A - B if C == +
 B - A if C == -
```

So, my output would be:

```
> new_df
   A  B C   D
1  1  1 +   0
2 54  2 - -52
3 23  4 - -19
4  2 65 + -63
```

Comment: Can `C` be any other values, or only +/- ?

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that only two conditions, `+` and `-`, are in column `C`.

```
df$D <- with(df, ifelse(C %in% "+", A - B, B - A))
df
#    A  B C   D
# 1  1  1 +   0
# 2 54  2 - -52
# 3 23  4 - -19
# 4  2 65 + -63
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create a data frame. Also, I don't like to use `df` for variable names since there is a `df()` function:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 54, 23, 2), 
                  B = c(1, 2, 4, 65), 
                  C = c("+", "-", "-", "+"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Assuming that `C` is only `+` or `-`, you can use `dplyr::mutate()` and test using `ifelse()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(D = ifelse(C == "+", A - B, B - A))
```

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr`:

If there are definitely only `+` and `-` in the C column you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
     mutate(D = ifelse(C == '+', A - B, B - A))
```

I would generally do:

```
df2 <- df %>%
     mutate(D = ifelse(C == '+', A - B,
                ifelse(C == '-', B - A, NA)))
```

Just in case there are some that do not have `+` or `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to evaluate the arithmetic information in column C (as in addition or subtraction), you can use `eval(parse(txt))` (more about that here: [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string#1743796)).

```
## Transforming into a matrix (simplifies everything into characters)
df_mat <- as.matrix(df)

## Function for evaluation the rows
eval.row <- function(row) {
    eval(parse(text= paste(row[1], row[3], row[2])))
}

## For the first row
eval.row(df_mat[1,])
# [1] 2

## For the whole data frame
apply(df_mat, 1, eval.row)
# [1]  2 52 19 67

## Updating the data.frame
df$D <- apply(df_mat, 1, eval.row)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing information about `eval` and `parse`, but it seems like the OP was asking something more straightforward. Here `+` and `-` is just a symbol to indicate `A - B` or `B - A`.

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited my answer to reflect the nuance.

Comment: Look at the output OP expects and then see whether your output matches what is expected

Answer (score 0):

This answer should work for you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19000310/6395612

You can use with like this:

```
df['D'] = with(df, ifelse(C=='+', A - B, B - A))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base solution:

```
df$D = (df$B-df$A)*sign((df$C=="-")-0.5)
#    A  B C   D
# 1  1  1 +   0
# 2 54  2 - -52
# 3 23  4 - -19
# 4  2 65 + -63
```

can also be written `df <- transform(df, D = (B-A)*sign((C=="-")-0.5))`